# How can I pass function keys in Gnome terminal to Emacs

Tags: emacs, gnome-terminal, function-keys

I like to use Emacs in the terminal with out X(`emacs -nw`). But the problem is I can't use function keys(f1 ... f12) in gnome terminal. How can I pass them to Emacs in gnome-terminal?

If it's not possible in gnome-terminal, I would be interested to know any other terminal which can pass them.

BTW, I am using
ubuntu 11.04,
emacs 23.3 and 24
gnome-terminal:2.32.1

EDIT:
These are the characters that Emacs is receiving in -nw from gnome-terminal
f5       [15~]
f6       [17~]
f7       [18~]
f8       [19~]
f9       [20~]
f10      [21~]
f11      [23~]
f12      [24~]

and with prefixes C &  M
C-f6     [17;5~]
M-f6     [17;3~]
...

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/187181/i-have-started-using-emacs-with-nw-option-ctrl-home-and-ctrl-end-dont-work

Comment: @Dysaster, thanks for the comment, Similar but couldn't get it work. I am not sure how to assign/bind these characters(please see the Edit).

Comment: Do you get `[15~]` or `^[[15~`? Mine is the second one.

Comment: hmm.. I just noticed that, if I dont load paredit-mode gnome-terminal working fine..